# How to choose between a Report (Subreports) Or Other Solution SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am preparing a building management system currently working on a report. This report will include information of Apartment around 25-30 fields and then for each apartment rooms information will be displayed. Each room will have around 20 fields.

We can restrict this report to one apartment at a time. So let say we will have a Apartment which will total of 5 rooms. I don't know how to implement prepare this report so user will be able to print this easily and data will be easy to understand.

One of my friend said to me that prepare a report for apartment and then add a subreport for rooms. But how i can show around 25 fields of apartment and then 20 fields of room.

Is subreport a good solution to this scenario? If no please suggest other possible solution.
How to manage fields and still make it a easy to understand and printable solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is a good candidate for having 2 Data Sources & 2 Tablix regions (Or 1 tablix region, and textboxes in a header).

First Data Source has only the apartment fields, and should be a single record. Second Data Source has the room fields for that specific apartment.

Have a tablix at the top displaying the apartment information. Seeing as you are only viewing one apartment at a time, there should only be a single record. (Maybe display this information using textboxes in a header so as to repeat it on each page.)

Have a second tablix below the first (or in the body of the report) with relevant room information.

Comment: Thanks Scurffy. Your explained it very well. I am new to SSRS and don't know how to use 2 data sources in one report. I can add two tablix regions but two data sources :( can you suggest some tutorial. Sorry if i am bothering you too much.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. I meant to say 2 "DataSets". You should only need a single DataSource.  I apologize for the error. When you have the 2 DataSets, open the appropriate Tablix properties and set the "Dataset Name". If you decide to use header textboxes for the apartment information, you will have to use the =First() method in an expression.